# Меню с неограниченными вложениями

Tags: php

Имеется таблица в БД, где хранятся элементы меню:

```
ИД | Название | Связь
1  | Авто     | 0
2  | Авиа     | 0
3  | Жигули   | 1
4  | Москвич  | 1
5  | Мото     | 0
6  | Ту-134   | 2
7  | Иж (Ю-5) | 5
```

Вот пример таблицы с записями. Надеюсь, понятно представлена конструкция. Вопрос такой - как из этой таблицы построить меню с неограниченной вложенностью? То, что через цикл, это понятно. Или через рекурсию - уже два дня бьюсь и никак не могу составить верное решение.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Задачка решается [поиском в ширину](http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9F%D0%BE%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BA_%D0%B2_%D1%88%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BD%D1%83) с небольшими модификациями.

```
// Корневой элемент меню
$menu = array('id' => 0, 'name' => 'menuRoot');

// Помещаем корневой элемент меню в очередь
$queue = array(&$menu);

$i = 0;
while (count($queue) > $i)
{
    // Извлекаем элемент из очереди и делаем его текущим
    $elem = &$queue[$i++];

    // Загружаем подменю текущего элемента
    $res = mysql_query('SELECT id, name FROM menuTable WHERE link='.$elem['id']);

    // Заполняем подменю текущего элемента
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))
    {
        if (!isset($elem['subMenu']))
            $elem['subMenu'] = array();

        $elem['subMenu'] []= array('id' => $row['id'], 'name' => $row['name']);

        // Добавляем элемент подменю в очередь на загрузку из БД
        $queue []= &$elem['subMenu'][count($elem['subMenu']) - 1];
    }
}

var_dump($menu);
```

Comment: Всегда хотел эту штуку в работе увидеть, причем обоснованно)

Comment: Не понял. Ведь работает вроде бы? Только не понятна эта строка.
$menu = array('id' => 0, 'name' => 'menuRoot');

Comment: @new_russian_man, эта строка служит как бы корнем древовидного меню, своеобразное облегчение процесса. Если бы я делал несколько корневых элементов это бы увеличило объем кода, к тому же я не думаю, что добавление фиктивного элемента сильно повлияет на производительность :) По идеи меню хранящееся в вашей БД начинается как массив элементов подменю корневого (фиктивного) элемента - `$menu['subMenu']`

Comment: Странно но выдает ошибку

Warning: mysql_fetch_assoc(): supplied argument is not a valid MySQL result resource in w:\www\11.php on line 35
array(2) { ["id"]=> int(0) ["name"]=> string(8) "menuRoot" }
что то не нравится ему этв строка 
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res))

Comment: при выполнении SQL-запроса в mysql_query произошла ошибка, в результате чего в `$res` вернулся `FALSE`. Проверьте установилось ли соединение с БД, выбрана ли текущей БД (mysql_select_db).

Answer (score 1):

В таблице "Меню" добавляем поле parent_id - ID родительского элемента меню. (У "верхних" элементов равен 0).
В php - рекурсивная функция, примерно такая:

```
function get_menu_elements($parent_id = 0){
   $result = //Выборка из БД с условием WHERE parent_id=$parent_id
   for($i=0;$i<count($result);$i++)
      $result[$i]['children'] = get_menu_elements($result[$i]['id']);
   return $result;
}
```

Comment: Ну во-первых автор четко дал понять - меню неограниченной вложенности, во-вторых не нужно создавать parent_id - его роль выполняет поле link.

Comment: Да, поле связь не заметила - parent_id значит уже есть.

По поводу ограниченности рекурсии что-то не поняла - с каких пор она накладывает ограничения ?..

Comment: Ну как вам сказать...в PHP есть ограничение(как и в большинстве языков) на величину стека вызовов функций/методов. А так как вы используете рекурсию, то для неограниченного по вложенности меню это может привести к ошибке.

Comment: Тут суть в том, что мы изначально не знаем степени вложенности, то ли 2, то ли 1000.